# Como minimizar script jquery

Tags: jquery

Existe alguma forma de minimizar/simplificar esse script em jquery?

```
$("#men").click(function() {
    $("#men").addClass('active-men').addClass('selected');
    $("#wom").removeClass('active-wom').removeClass('selected');
    $("#opt").removeClass('active').removeClass('selected');
});
$("#wom").click(function() {
    $("#men").removeClass('active-men').removeClass('selected');
    $("#wom").addClass('active-wom').addClass('selected');
    $("#opt").removeClass('active').removeClass('selected');
});
$("#opt").click(function() {
    $("#men").removeClass('active-men').removeClass('selected');
    $("#wom").removeClass('active-wom').removeClass('selected');
    $("#opt").addClass('active').addClass('selected');
});
```

O html é esse:

```
<option id="men" class="op men">Menino</option>
<option id="wom" class="op wom">Menina</option>
<option id="opt" class="op opt">Outro</option>
```

Já tentei diversas vezes, mas n obtive sucesso! Podem me ajudar?

(edit) Essas funções também poderia ser incluídas no script?:

```
$("#men").click(function() {
    $(".avatar-men").removeClass('avatar-men').addClass('avatar-men-active');
    $(".avatar-wom-active").removeClass('avatar-wom-active').addClass('avatar-wom');
});
$("#wom").click(function() {
    $(".avatar-wom").removeClass('avatar-wom').addClass('avatar-wom-active');
    $(".avatar-men-active").removeClass('avatar-men-active').addClass('avatar-men');
});
$("#opt").click(function() {
    $(".avatar-men-active").removeClass('avatar-men-active').addClass('avatar-men');
    $(".avatar-wom-active").removeClass('avatar-wom-active').addClass('avatar-wom');
});
```

HTML do mesmo:

```
<div class="avt avatar-men"></div>
<div class="avt avatar-wom"></div>
```

Comment: Porque estás a usar `option`? tens um select? podes explicar qual o efeito essas classes fazem e a funcionalidade que queres fazer?

Comment: São opções para um formulário.

Comment: Se explicares melhor vais ter respostas melhores. Assim como está parece-me má ideia pois o elemento `option` não dá para customizar em browsers diferentes, assim não faz sentido ter classes e não vejo onde tens o atributo `value` que seria semanticamente correto. Se explicares o que queres fazer posso dar um exemplo com código.

Comment: o option coloquei apenas por teste, tbm funciona com div. Eu pego o valor do html dentro option para enviar no formulario.

Comment: Por passos então: O que precisas é enviar a opção escolhida num formulário certo? Caso "sim" qual a ideia das classes `active-xx` e `selected`?

Comment: O formulário pega o html da classe selected e a classe active é apenas o design que muda.

Comment: Porque não usar o `value` do select e enviar isso no formulário? Mudar layout de `option` não funciona em todos os browsers. Como estás a submeter o formulário?

Comment: Porquê eu não posso alterar o desenho que é feito sob medida! Select não se encaixa aqui.

Comment: Se queres usar elementos `option` deves usar dentro de `select`, se queres fazer o teu próprio HTML para simular um `select` aí tudo bem. Nesse caso era bom colocares na pergunta esse HTML e css para vermos o que as classes fazem e como estás a submeter os dados desse "select".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

como o [@Sergio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/129/sergio) apontou, o seu `HTML` não parece ser semanticamente correto, então é interessante é interessante que você abra uma pergunta pedindo uma revisão do mesmo.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".op", function () {
  var that = $(this);
  var outros = $(".op[id!='" + this.id + "']");
  that.addClass('selected').addClass('active-' + this.id);
  outros.removeClass('selected').removeClass(function () {
    return "active-" + this.id;
  })
});
```

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

.active-men {
  border-color: steelblue;
}

.active-wom {
  border-color: crimson;
}

.active-opt {
  border-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="men" class="op men">Menino</div>
<div id="wom" class="op wom">Menina</div>
<div id="opt" class="op opt">Outro</div>
```

dependendo de como estiver o seu HTML, você poderá simplificar um pouco mais.:

```
$(document).on("click", "[data-tipo]", function () {
  var that = $(this);
  that.addClass('selected').addClass('active-' + this.id);
  that.siblings().removeClass('selected').removeClass(function () {
    return "active-" + this.id;
  })
});
```

no mais, se você precisa de um estilo que será aplicado à apenas um elemento, talvez você deva usar o `id` na composição do seletor.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".op", function () {
  var that = $(this);
  that.addClass('selected');
  that.siblings().removeClass('selected');
});
```

```css
.op {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

#men.selected {
  border-color: steelblue;
}

#wom.selected {
  border-color: crimson;
}

#opt.selected {
  border-color: teal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="men" class="op men">Menino</div>
<div id="wom" class="op wom">Menina</div>
<div id="opt" class="op opt">Outro</div>
```

**EDIT**

Olha, você não está se ajudando ao utilizar esta estrutura de CSS, de aconselho que ao invés de ficar alternando entre duas classes, faça apenas a adição/remoção de um classe especifica. Então, no lugar de `.avatar-wom` e `.avatar-wom-active`, o ideal seria `.avatar-wom` e `.avatar-wom.active`.

Em todo caso, segue abaixo o seu código simplificado.

```js
$(document).on("click", ".op", function () {
  var that = $(this);
  var outros = $(".op[id!='" + this.id + "']");
  that.addClass('selected').addClass('active-' + this.id);
  outros.removeClass('selected').removeClass(function () {
    return "active-" + this.id;
  });
  
  $(".avatar-men, .avatar-men-active")
    .toggleClass("avatar-men", this.id != "men")
    .toggleClass("avatar-men-active", this.id == "men");
  $(".avatar-wom, .avatar-wom-active")
    .toggleClass("avatar-wom", this.id != "wom")
    .toggleClass("avatar-wom-active", this.id == "wom");
});
```

```css
.op {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
}

.selected {
  background-color: gainsboro;
}

#men.selected {
  border-color: rgb(63,81,181);
}

#wom.selected {
  border-color: rgb(244,67,54);
}

#opt.selected {
  border-color: rgb(0,150,136);
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.avatar-men img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.avatar-wom img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.avatar-men-active {
  background-color: rgba(63,81,181, 0.5);
  border-color: rgb(63,81,181);
}

.avatar-wom-active {
  background-color: rgba(244,67,54, 0.5);
  border-color: rgb(244,67,54);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="men" class="op men">Menino</div>
<div id="wom" class="op wom">Menina</div>
<div id="opt" class="op opt">Outro</div>

<div class="avatar avatar-men">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145859.svg" />
</div>

<div class="avatar avatar-wom">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145862.svg" />
</div>
```

E por fim um exemplo com o CSS alterado com a sugestão que dei antes.:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".op, .avatar", function () {
  var option = $("." + this.dataset.id);
  option.addClass('active');
  option.siblings().removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.op {
  border: 2px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 3px;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.op.men.active {
  background-color: rgba(63,81,181,0.2);
  border-color: rgb(63,81,181);
}

.op.wom.active {
  background-color: rgba(244,67,54,0.2);
  border-color: rgb(244,67,54);
}

.op.opt.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,150,136,0.2);
  border-color: rgb(0,150,136);
}

.avatar {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 128px;
  height: 128px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  background-color: gainsboro;
  margin-right: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.avatar img {
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.avatar.active img {
  filter: grayscale(0%);
}

.avatar.men.active {  
  background-color: rgba(63,81,181, 0.2);
  border-color: rgb(63,81,181);
}

.avatar.wom.active {
  background-color: rgba(244,67,54, 0.2);
  border-color: rgb(244,67,54);
}

.avatar.opt.active {
  background-color: rgba(0,150,136, 0.2);
  border-color: rgb(0,150,136);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="options">
  <div data-id="men" class="op men">Menino</div>
  <div data-id="wom" class="op wom">Menina</div>
  <div data-id="opt" class="op opt">Outro</div>
</div>

<div id="avatars">
  <div data-id="men" class="avatar men">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145859.svg" />
  </div>
  <div data-id="wom" class="avatar wom">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/145/145862.svg" />
  </div>
  <div data-id="opt" class="avatar opt">
    <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/344/344296.svg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente! Você é fera. Poderia me ajudar em outra coisa? Decidi fazer outra alteração no click, editei a pergunta e coloquei no final o código que gostaria de simplificar.

Comment: No caso eu gostaria de inclui-lo ao principal e não separado.

Comment: @PauloSérgioFilho editei a resposta.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado!